# Is it possible to shoot tethered with Aperture using a Canon 5D mark i?

Tags: canon, apple-aperture, tethering, digital

Google is swamped with walkthroughs for the canon 5D mark ii & iii. I am wondering if anyone has managed to get a tethered shoot setup working with the original 5D on a macbook. If so, how was it achieved?

I am interested in using it under aperture 3.4 (not LR) and am running OSX 10.8.

Comment: Could you shoot tethered using the eos utility and then have eos utility load an application, such as aperture, with the just-shot image? Similary, could you make aperture monitor a folder and show the just-shot photo?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Aperture camera compatibility list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4176?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) you should be able to shoot tethered with the original Canon 5D with Aperture 3.0.3 and higher. The camera should be set to `PC Connect` communication mode. On page 123 of the [manual](http://rtvfstockroom.fullerton.edu/Manuals_files/Canon5DManual.pdf) it is explained how to set the communication mode of the Canon 5D.

Comment: I've used my Canon 5D in PC connect mode with aperture and it's not working. In Aperture's tether panel the camera appears instantly in the list and then disappears.